# Jade Empire for iOS, are the romance sub-plots intact?

Tags: version-differences, jade-empire

I played Jade Empire on XBox long time ago, and now the iOS version of the game looks rather nice. I'm planning to buy and play it on iPad, but I have some reservations. I'm hoping for an answer from someone who has actually played both XBox (or PC is the same I guess?) and iOS versions and can confirm from personal experience:

Have they kept *all* the romance plot options, including the same-sex and threesome options?